# The angular app is getting access but webapi is not getting accessed when called from another system but works tried within the server. Why?

Tags: c#, angular, iis, asp.net-web-api

today I spent around straight 10 hours on one issue and it's not getting solved. I am very new to angular, webapi and deployment etc.

Please help me if you can.

See.

I have a server where on IIS I have deployed

1. a Web API project (Port: 81)
2. an angular app (Port: 80)

Within the server when I try to access the angular app in the browser using the IP address and port number then it works and calls the Web API methods where needed. Fine.

But when I try to access the angular app from my pc which is in the same network then the app gets accessed but webAPI is not getting retrieved and returns an error in the Network tab and console of chrome.

```
Error: Uncaught (in promise): C: {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":"http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:81/api/Types/TopType","ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:81 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
```

The angular app allows the headers, origins and everything. (*)

Also, I tried to access the web API from my pc using the browser ipaddress:81 then it returned "taking too long to respond" message hence not accessed.

But I think that my PC doesn't need to access the API since I am calling angular app and that in turn its calling the API in the server but not sure.

On server, in `env.js` of angular app, I have provide the URL for API using the IP address and port instead of the localhost:81.

Also, the reason to keep angular app on port 80 is when I assign it some other port then it stops getting accessed.

Comment: Web.Api is project is .NET project?

Comment: yes it is. coorect

Answer (score 1):

@Afaaqa can you try to put these in the CreateHostBuilder method inside Program.cs

```
builder.UseUrls("[https or http]://*:[your port number]");
```

remove [] also while replacing

Comment: @Afaaqa after adding this line you have to use url like this [https or http]://YOUR_IP_V4:PORT_NUMBER
and also check your system firewall may be it's blocking requests.